Issue with dark mode not working after reboot in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I enabled dark mode in Ubuntu 24.04. However, dark mode isn't enabled with the file system, settings, and others areas. It was working fine, but after reboot, dark mode isn't working anymore.
My Machine specifications:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble



Not sure what went wrong Asir, but when it comes to themes and dark mode I prefer the "do it yourself" method.  You might want to try the following:
sudo apt install gnome-colors
Then when you use settings, appearance, icons, you can choose
the colors of your folders (directories).
Then to get a dark theme that is easy on your eyes type this:
sudo apt install gnome-themes-extra-data
....and then choose the Adwaita-dark theme which will now appear in your appearance settings. Should work in Gnome, Cinnamon (based on Gnome2) and also XFCE.  Haven't tried it on other desktops.
